# angular2 unit test of nested services

Tags: service, angular, code-injection, provider

Im trying to write some Unit Test for a service like:

```
export class Service1 {
...
    public constructor(service2: Service2, service3: Service3) {}
...
}
```

where Service2 contains, in turn, Service3:

```
export class Service2 {
...
    public constructor(service3: Service3, stringa: string) {}
...
}
```

i starting test 
in a really awful way, like:

```
 it("check XXX", () => {
   let service3: Service3= new Service3();
   let service2: service2= new service2(service3, "stringa");
   let service1: Service1 = new Service1(service2, service3);
   expect(X).toEqual(X);
 });
```

but now, i'm using  beforeEachProviders and what happen with this:

```
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      provide(Service2, { useclass: MockService2}),
      provide(Service3, { useclass: MockService3}),
      provide('stringa', { useValue: "stringa"}),
      Service1
    ];
  });

  it('check XXX ', inject(
  [Service2, Service3], (service2: Service2, service3: Service3) => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  }));
```

is:

```
  Failed: No provider for String! (Service2-> String).
```

Could someboby help me ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject the string value from dependency injection, you need to use the `@Inject` decorator:

```
export class Service2 {
  ...
  public constructor(service3: Service3, @Inject('stringa') stringa: string) {}
  ...
}
```

As a matter of fact, injection relies on parameter types by default if you don't use the `@Inject` decorator.

Comment: I had already used  @Inject decorator in the constructor, but not in the Mock service !! really thanks you !!!